# If form option value select equals then redirect PHP/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form on my page with a dropdown of counties. I want to somehow, with jQuery or PHP say that if a certain county is selected then redirect otherwise process the form.

I've created a fiddle to try and explain...

http://jsfiddle.net/KVjAc/

Comment: post your applicable code and link(demo), note that jsFiddle has no association with Stackoverflow and it may cause to close your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps(if you need a javascript/jquery solution),

```
$('#selectbox_ID').change( function() {
     if($(this).val() == "your country"){

     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just submit the form and use a php [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) command for the values you want to redirect. That would be the first thing to check in the form processor script.

No need for javascript unless you are using ajax to refresh parts of the page based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#county').on('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'cheshire' || value == 'city of london' || value == 'durham') {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
        }
    })
});
```

**EDIT:** Also, you need to add values to your option elements: `<option value="cheshire">Cheshire</option>`